# How to create a command that deletes a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a bat file that is trying to delete a file until job's done. 
But after first attempt it just fails and nothing happens. I'm looking for something like `try catch`.

My current script looks like this:

```
:loop
TIMEOUT 1
del "D:\VM\1.docx"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set file="D:\VM\1.docx"
:loop
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
del %file%
IF EXIST %file% GOTO loop
```

like this?

corrected spaces in first line

Comment: Sorry, when I run it it says `del` -> `the syntax of the command is incorrect`

Comment: sorry, write the first line like this (without spaces before and after the =):

set file="D:\VM\1.docx"

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for an answer, I' mark it when it will be possible to do. And it's funny that question that has no similar answer (I always google before asking) with only 7 views has a downvote :)

Comment: indeed, there is someone around that feels himself very proud of making fun of others. 
Glad it worked. Batch is so terribly old, that if you are not using this much you always have to do a big search for solutions... :-)